# Git undo merging 3 branches

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, mergetool

I am not very familiar with Git. I have the basics down, but thats about it.

Anyway, my friend walked me through merging these 3 branches. He left me to run the mergetools part myself though. I didn't do the merge correctly, but had already pushed the changes. Is there some way I can undo my changes so it goes back to being 3 different branches, and then merge again?

edit*

Not 100% sure if it matters, but 2 of the branches are from upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the commit ID of the last clean state (i.e. the commit before the merge) for example with `git log` and reset to that.

```
git reset --hard abcdef01
```

After that, force push your old state.

```
git push -f origin
```

**Be aware:** `reset --hard` will discard unstaged changes, so be sure to have a clean working directory. Do a `git stash` if not sure.
Additionally, this will only work without problems, if you didn't do any further work on the merged state, i.e. you didn't commit anything since then.

Man pages:

- [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
- [git-stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: I thought i remember reading that you can't reset --hard if you've already pushed your changes. Maybe I read you're not supposed to, not that I can't? Either way, is there a way to test to see if this works before pushing again?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it matters, but 2 of the branches are from upstream.

Comment: You can always do anything you want in your local repository. It's just not recommended, because you'll change an already pushed (published) history.

Answer (score -1):

You may use `git revert <>`, but there would be so many commits between the last clean commit and the current `head`. I don't know much of the git commands, but there must be a way to print all the commits in between. You may write some script to extract only the SHAs and revert them all.

I am not 100% sure about this though. :)